# store posted variables from a form long time

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a form which is passing a number array like `(56,78,98)`. I have stored that array in a variable called $array.

eg:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $checkbox_values=$_POST['checkbox_values];
$array= implode(',',$checkbox_values);
 }
```

`$_POST['checkbox_values]` is values of check boxes from a form.

I need to retrieve value of $array after the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition. I am using zend frame work. How can I use $array after if condition? or how can I use session or cookie in zend?

Thanks!!!

Comment: in Zend you should use if($this->_request->isPost()) if($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()) { $data = $form->getValues() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could assign the array directly to the session using Zend_Session_Namespace:

```
//you can initialize the session namespace almost anywhere.
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('form')
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $checkbox_values=$_POST['checkbox_values'];
    //will assign values to session namespace 'form' as key 'checkbox_values' as an array
    //session namespace will also accept objects and scalar values.
    $session->checkbox_values = implode(',', $checkbox_values);
    //$array= implode(',',$checkbox_values);
 }
```

you can use the array any way you choose. You can pass it to the view...
`$this->view->checkboxValues = $session->checkbox_values;`

or you can pass it to your favorite model, what ever you need to do you can do. the session will remain until you unset it or overwrite it.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a single quote

```
$checkbox_values = $_POST['checkbox_values'];
```

otherwise everything looks fine.